# Is zero (0) an even or odd number?

Tags: php, zero, parity

**Not a request for code of any type.**

Let's say you are randomly generating a number between zero and ten and are doing so until you receive just an even number. Is zero an available result?

Are the evens 0-10:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

-OR-

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

Comment: This may be worth a read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not programming.  See [this question on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-zero-odd-or-even).

Answer (score 7):

Mathematically, 0 is even. PHP has no built-in notion of even.

A (mathematically correct) test for even parity is checking if the number vanishes mod 2. This test is implemented as `$number % 2 == 0`. For zero you can quickly check that 0 mod 2 is 0, and would be considered even.

Answer (score 3):

Zero is an even number. So, yes, it's even "in PHP," too. As a test, `0 % 2 === 0` => `0` is even.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a month late but the best way to determine if a number is even or odd is by using a simple mathematical formula.

```
Even: 2n or 2 x n;
Odd: 2n+1 or (2 x n)+1;
```

Using the two equations above (where n>=0), you can determine that 0 is even.

```
Even: 2(0) = 0;
Odd: 2(0)+1 = 1;
```

So using the lowest possible number where n is greater than or equal to zero, it is proven that 0 is even.